# Angular 6 - Revert form fields changed values on submit

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms, onsubmit

In my angular 6 application, there is a profile update section, the profile form loads initially with prefilled details i.e Details saved during registration.

The form looks like below

[image]

Title, First Name, Last Name, Email Address are output fields hence cannot be edited.

New Email Address becomes mandatory if touched and Confirm Email is mandatory if the new email is entered.

Users can edit the new email address, mobile number and Daytime Phone number fields.

On Submit, the backend service is called to update the user profile. If this service is down I have to revert the changed form fields to how it was loaded initially.

I am using the following code to reset email, confirm email, mobile number and daytime phone number.

```
updateProfile(){
    this.http.post('https://testurl/user/updateProfile', param, options).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("Profile update successful:", data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Profile update error!", error);
            if(error.status === '500'){ // If service is down
                this.profileForm.controls['newemail'].reset();
                this.profileForm.controls['confirmemail'].reset();
                this.profileForm.controls['mobile'].reset();
                this.profileForm.controls['daytimephone'].reset();          
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But this gives the below error. And reset anyways simply empties the fields.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
```

I want to find if fields are modified and revert their value to the initial one if exist.

To be more clear, Say user modifies the following fields

```
new email => testabc10@gmail.com
confirm email => testabc10@gmail.com
Daytime Phone => +44123456789
```

When this form is submitted assuming the backend is down, how can I get back the Daytime Phone Number's initial value?

Please guide, thanks

Comment: Clear the modifies field once the backend response getting success. Until don't clear the field. Correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the modified fields? Also, my intention is not to clear the field values rather retain its old value ( value when onload )

Comment: You can get the modified field values like `this.profileForm.get('newemail').value`  and so on. You should keep the value until the api response will get success. After we got success response, We can clear the field use `this.profileForm.get('newemail').reset()` and son on.

Comment: I got your point, As you say the values of each form control can be saved but reset simply makes the field empty right, in my case, I want to set form control with the value that it had before the user made the changes.
Also even reset is giving the following error
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a method that sets the initial values for the controls. Probably right after the profile is loaded. It seems like a good idea to call that same method if the web request failed.

```js
profile: Profile;

setProfileFormValue() {
   this.profileForm.controls['newemail'].setValue('');
   this.profileForm.controls['confirmemail'].setValue('');
   this.profileForm.controls['mobile'].setValue(this.profile.mobile);
   this.profileForm.controls['daytimephone']
      .setValue(this.profile.daytimephone);
}
updateProfile() {
   this.http.post('https://testurl/user/updateProfile', param, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
         console.log("Profile update successful:", data);
      },
      error => {
         console.log("Profile update error!", error); // console.error instead of console.log?
         if(error.status === '500') { // If service had an internal server error (not necessary down)
            this.setProfileFormValue();
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: Tried ```this.myForm.markAsPristine()``` it makes the current form pristine so all the entered fields are still the same

Comment: and what about the whole algorithm described in the answer? (: does it work?

Comment: Can you help me with the code snippet pls? 
Maybe I have not understood you correctly.
I just did this

`updateProfile(){
 this.http.post('https://testurl/user/updateProfile', param, options).subscribe(
  data => {
            console.log("Profile update successful:", data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Profile update error!", error);
            if(error.status === '500'){ // If service is down
                this.myForm.markAsPristine()          
            }
        }
    );
}
`

Comment: it seems like the question was changed since my answer posted (Or I became smarter, which I don't recognize as a possibility). The answer didn't look relevant anymore. I updated the answer. Does it solve the issue now? (: